# Loading js files in order using shim

Tags: jquery, requirejs

After reading the docs and trying a few things out, I'm not sure why the following code doesnt load the scripts in order:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: '../js/',
shim: {
   jQuery       : 'vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min',
   chosen       : 'plugins/chosen.jquery',
   swiper       : 'plugins/idangerous.swiper',
   sidr         : 'plugins/query.sidr.min',
   animations   : 'animations',
   forms        : 'forms',
   partials     : 'partials',
   scripts      : 'scripts'
},
urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});


require(['vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min','plugins/chosen.jquery','plugins/idangerous.swiper','plugins/jquery.sidr.min', 'animations', 'forms', 'partials', 'scripts'], function( $, chosen, swiper, sidr, animations, forms, partials, scripts ) {
    console.log( $, animations, forms, partials, scripts );
});
```

Essentially I'm wanting to load the files in the plugin folder after jquery but before all other scripts.

Comment: This will never cal it in order. You might want to look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581611/load-files-in-specific-order-with-requirejs. Beside, jQuery does not need a shim since it is AMD compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have confused `paths` with `shim`. You use `paths` to define module names and map them to specific files. Moreover, once you have defined a name, then you *must* refer to this module *by this same name* everywhere. Otherwise, RequireJS will think you are referring to a different module. For instance, if `"foo"` maps to `"scripts/foo"` and you do something like `request(["foo", "scripts/foo", ...`, for RequireJS `"foo"` and `"scripts/foo"` are not the same module.

The name for the jQuery module must be `"jquery"`, all lower-caps, or you'll run into trouble at some point.

Provided you specified everything and that I understood it properly, the following should do what you were aiming for. The `exports` field contain `???` because I cannot know what you need to export there. The 3 plugins do not have an `exports` field because I've assumed they are jQuery plugins and it is not strictly speaking necessary to give them one. However, it is good practice to give them an `exports` value to help RequireJS ensure everything is loaded in older IE browsers.

Moreover, I've taken what you have in your question at face value. If some of the modules here were created by you, then they should use `define` and list their dependencies as the first argument of the `define` call, and **not** use a shim. Or if some of these modules are third-party modules that do call `define`, the same applies.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../js/',
    paths: {
        jquery       : 'vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min',
        chosen       : 'plugins/chosen.jquery',
        swiper       : 'plugins/idangerous.swiper',
        sidr         : 'plugins/query.sidr.min',
    },
    shim: {
        chosen: ['jquery'],
        swiper: ['jquery'],
        sidr: ['jquery'],
        animations: {
            deps: ['chosen', 'swiper', 'sidr'],
            exports: ???,
        },
        forms: {
            deps: ['chosen', 'swiper', 'sidr'],
            exports: ???,
        },
        partials: {
            deps: ['chosen', 'swiper', 'sidr'],
            exports: ???,
        },
        scripts: {
            deps: ['chosen', 'swiper', 'sidr'],
            exports: ???,
        },
    },
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});


require(['jquery','chosen','swiper','sidr', 'animations', 'forms', 'partials', 'scripts'], function( $, chosen, swiper, sidr, animations, forms, partials, scripts ) {
    console.log( $, animations, forms, partials, scripts );
});
```