# RequireJS script load order

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

I am trying to load bootstrap and kendo-ui using requirejs but they both depend on jquery to be loaded first.

Currently all three scripts are loading async (from CDNs) with:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": [
            "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min",
            "libs/jquery"
        ],
        'bootstrap': [
            'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min',
            'libs/bootstrap'
        ],
        'kendo': [
            'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.ui.core.min',
            'libs/kendo'
        ]
    }
})

require(['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'kendo'], function () {
    $('body').html('hi!')
})
```

How do get it to not load other scripts until jquery is loaded completely?

I assume there is a nicer way than:

```
require(['jquery'], function () {
    require(['bootstrap', 'kendo'], function () {
        $('body').html('hi!')
    })
})
```

If that even works (off top of my head).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load files in specific order with RequireJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581611/load-files-in-specific-order-with-requirejs)

Comment: Read that before, where is the answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [shim-option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) like,

```
require.config({
   paths: {
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min',
        'bootstrap': 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min',
        'kendo': 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.ui.core.min'
    }, 

    // Use shim for plugins that does not support ADM
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': ['jquery'],
        'kendo': ['jquery']
    }
});
```

Also, refer the [example-of-jquery-shim](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-shim)