# Highcharts Error #27 with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, requirejs

I've just recently upgraded to Highcharts 5.0.12 from 4.xx and I'm now running into Highcharts error #27. The error states that I need to include/import boost.js and boost-canvas.js. I've imported them and I seem to be getting error #27 still. Below is my require.config.js:

```
paths: {
    'text': 'thirdparty/requirejs-text/text',
    'js': 'js',
    'templates': 'templates',
    'moment': 'thirdparty/moment/moment',
    'highcharts-boost-canvas': 'thirdparty/highcharts/boost-canvas',
    'highcharts-boost': 'thirdparty/highcharts/boost',
    'highcharts': 'thirdparty/highcharts/highcharts',
    'highmaps': 'thirdparty/highcharts/highcharts-map-module'
},
shim: {
    'bootstrap': {deps: ['jquery']},
    'jquery-ui': {deps: ['jquery']},
    'datatables': {deps: ['jquery']},
    'highcharts-boost-canvas' : {deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'Highcharts'},
    'highcharts-boost' : {deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'Highcharts'},
    'highcharts': {deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'Highcharts'},
    'highmaps': {deps: ['Highcharts'], exports: 'Highcharts' },
    'jquery.cookie': {deps: ['jquery']},
    'jquery.history': {deps: ['jquery']}
}
```

Am I missing a step or doing something wrong in my setup?

Comment: It looks like you tried to include the file "/code/js/highcharts.js" while they provide a single file "/code/highcharts.js". They both have the same name which is confusing.

Comment: Have you tried to load boost/boost-canvas when Highcharts are loaded (I know that its async). Somehting like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581611/load-files-in-specific-order-with-requirejs