# requirejs jquery and boostrap load order

Tags: jquery, requirejs

Hi i have a question about loading bootstrap and js:

i have this code:

```
<script>
 var config = {
   paths: {
        "bootstrap": "plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min"
   },
   'shim': {
        'bootstrap': {
                deps: ['jquery']
        }
    },
 };
 require.config(config);
 require([
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap'
 ], function ($) {  
    $('#accordion-about').collapse();   
 });
</script>
```

it load the file correctly but not in the correct order.
it load bootstrap before jquery and it cause error:
**Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery**

Comment: This may help - although not an exact duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581611/load-files-in-specific-order-with-requirejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shim` section does not accept paths from `paths` so it must be a full path to file:

```
<script>
 var config = {
   paths: {
        "bootstrap": "plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min"
   },
   'shim': {
        'plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min': {
                deps: ['jquery']
        }
    },
 };
 require.config(config);
 require([
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap'
 ], function ($) {  
    $('#accordion-about').collapse();   
 });
</script>
```